# How to take notes using LaTeX during a lecture

Tags: editors, code-snippets

I'm a Windows 10 user and I wanna use LaTeX to make notes during lectures. But, as you know, it is not very efficient. So, after looking up on the internet, I found this ...

https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/

The author is a Vim user and he created snippets to make writing on LaTeX efficient.

My question is that is there any way to make snippets in windows too, in an editor other than Vim?

Comment: that is vim, not my favourite editor but it is available on windows, I don't think there is anything there linux specific.

Comment: Is there any way to do so in, say, Texmaker ?

Comment: I have never used texmaker but several here have, I'll let them answer that:-)

Comment: Thank you so much. It'll be of so much help. I need to configure the editor to use LaTeX as fast as I can.

Comment: Texstudio will be okay too.

Comment: I have not used texstudio either, you may want to edit your question to make it explicit that you are not just looking for windows vim code.

Comment: I've made an edit to the question.

Comment: Gummi is a very a simple latex editor (not learning curve) but have configurable snippets.

Comment: @Fran Will you please add an answer explaining what can one do with it ?

Comment: @DarkKnight Is just go to Edit > Preferences > Editor and you will fin a dialof to save or edit snippets. More information about that program already here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/923/11604